# No results showing for mysql select all

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello guys i am trying to show all the users pokemon were the table belongsto = there username here is my code
i have a connect on top of this has well

```
     // Get all the data from the "example" table
$result = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE
    belongsto='".$_SESSION['username']."'
AND (slot='0')'"; 
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table

    echo $row['pokemon'];

    echo $row['id'];

}
```

i have print red the username and there username is in the username session .
i think i mite be missing a ' or something i add  or mysql at the end of the query but then the pages dies with no error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not running the query and have an error in it. And you're not escaping strings going into query.
A proper version of the code would be

```
// escape a string going to query.
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']);
// create a query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='$username' AND slot=0"; 
// run a query and output possible error for debugging purposes.
$res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
// keep getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
// Print out the contents of each row into a table
  echo $row['pokemon'];
  echo $row['id'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that the final query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM user_pokemon WHERE belongsto='NAME' AND (slot='0')'
```

where NAME is the name you pass in.  If that is the case, there is an extra single quote at the end.  I presume you are getting a SQL error?